# Read out-loud program for pronunciation and proof-reading

Tags: web-apps, speech-synthesis, language

In iOS you can ask the computer to read a text out-loud using 'speech'. For me it's very useful, as I'm not a native speaker, to proof-read text and to check the pronunciation. The problem though is that I recently found out that that this last point was not always that good, the pronunciation for example seems to sound unnatural.

Do there exist other online (free or not too expensive) services that provide something similar to speech in iOS?

Comment: For English, I assume? Any other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NaturalReader](http://www.naturalreaders.com) has an [online TTS](http://www.naturalreaders.com/onlinetts.php) service which can:

1. Import documents from your PC, Dropbox, google drive or from  the web browser. you can also copy paste a text to get it read aloud.

[they](http://www.naturalreaders.com) also have  [NaturalReaderCloud](http://www.naturalreaders.com/cloud.php) which the following features:

1. 30 natural-sounding online voices
2. Text-to-speech
3. Convert to mp3
4. 4 offline voices
5. Cloud documents
6. Bookmark
7. and many more...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) - extension for Google Chrome. I am the author.